# my method definition is not found but i'm not sure why

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a storyboard with tabbed browsing.  One of the tabs is a table view.  The table is populated by a list of animal "titles".  when the title is pressed, a detailed view is opened that displays the title in addition to a sound and the number of times that the animal has been clicked.  I have a view controller set up.  I also have item.h/m and itemstore.h/m.  there is also a detailedviewcontroller.  my current problem is that in the item store i have two arays set up but right off the bat xcode is telling me that method definitions aren't found.  its also giving my undeclared identifier errors.

FSAnimalsViewController.h (this is my table view controller)

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FSDetailViewController.h"

@interface FSAnimalsViewController : UITableViewController
{
}
@end
```

FSAnimalsViewController.m

```
#import "FSAnimalsViewController.h"
#import "FSItemStore.h"
#import "FSItem.h"

@implementation FSAnimalsViewController
- (id)init
{
    // Call the superclass's designated initializer
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self)
    {
        UINavigationItem *n = [self navigationItem];

        [n setTitle:@"FoxSays"];

        // Create a new bar button item that will send
        // addNewItem: to ItemsViewController

        [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:[self editButtonItem]];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    return [self init];
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FSDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[FSDetailViewController alloc] init];

    NSArray *items = [[FSItemStore defaultStore] allItems];
    FSItem *selectedItem = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    // Give detail view controller a pointer to the item object in row
    [detailViewController setItem:selectedItem];

    // Push it onto the top of the navigation controller's stack
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController
                                           animated:YES];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[FSItemStore defaultStore] allItems] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Set the cell identifier
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BasicCell";

    // Reuse the cell from the identifier
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell if it doesn't exist
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Log the row for debugging
    NSLog(@"%d", [indexPath row]);

    // Get object from store
    FSItem *item = [[[FSItemStore defaultStore] allItems] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    // Set label to from property in object
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[item title]];

    return cell;
}


@end
```

FSItem.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>

@interface FSItem : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic) SystemSoundID *sound;
@property (nonatomic) int plays;


- (NSArray *)animals;
- (NSArray *)sounds;

@end
```

FSItem.m

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import "FSItem.h"

@implementation FSItem

NSString *title;
SystemSoundID *sound;
int plays;

- (NSArray *)animals
{
    NSArray *animals = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Dog",@"Cat",@"Bird",@"Mouse",@"Cow",@"Frog",@"Elephant",@"Duck",@"Fish",@"Seal",@"Fox", nil];

    return animals;
}

- (NSArray *)sounds
{
    NSArray *sounds = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"Woof.mp3",
                       @"Meow.mp3",
                       @"tweet.mp3",
                       @"Squeak.mp3",
                       @"Moo.mp3",
                       @"Croak.mp3",
                       @"Toot.mp3",
                       @"Quack.mp3",
                       @"Blub.mp3",
                       @"OWOwOw.mp3",
                       @"Fox.mp3",
                       nil];

    return sounds;
}

@end
```

FSItemStore.h

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class FSItem;


@interface FSItemStore : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *allItems;
}

@property (nonatomic) int i;





+ (FSItemStore *)defaultStore;


- (NSArray *)allItems;
- (NSArray *)animals;
- (NSArray *)sounds;
- (FSItem *)createItem;


@end
```

FSItemStore.m

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import "FSItem.h"
#import "FSItemStore.h"

@implementation FSItemStore

int i = 0;

- (NSArray *)allItems
{
    return allItems;
}



+ (FSItemStore *)defaultStore;
{
    static FSItemStore *defaultStore = nil;
    if(!defaultStore)
        defaultStore = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];

    return defaultStore;
}



- (FSItem *)createItem
    {
        FSItem *item = [[FSItem alloc] init];

        if (i < [animals count])
        {
            [item setTitle: [animals objectAtIndex: i]];
            [item setSound: [sounds objectAtIndex: i]];
            [item setPlays: 0];
            i++;

            [allItems addObject: item];
        }

        return item;

    }

@end
```

FSItemStore is where my problems seem to be.  Its saying that method definition for sounds and animals isn't found and both sounds and animals are undeclared identifiers.  Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that in your H file you are declaring that your class will implement a method called animals that will return an NSArray, and a method call sounds that will return another NSArray, but in your M file you are not implementing these methods.

In your FSItemStore.m you should implement these methods:

```
- (NSArray *)animals{
    //Do whatever this method is supposed to do, return an NSArray.
}
- (NSArray *)sounds
{
    //Do whatever this method is supposed to do, return an NSArray.
}
```

**EDIT**

If what you pretend is that FSItemStore inherits the methods from FSItem, you have to declare the interface that way:

```
@interface FSItemStore : FSItem  //FSItem instead of NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *allItems;
}
```

Comment: isn't that taken care of in FSItem.m though?

Comment: @ScottPfeiffer Not at all. If you pretend FSItemStore to inherit the methods from FSItem you should declare its interface the way I explain in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your code correctly you want to set one of the animals and sounds initialized in FSItem::sounds and FSItem::animals to the new item that you create in FSItemStore::createItem. So the animals and sounds methods should be executed ont eh correct object - the FSItem object. Change your code in FSItemStore::createItem to this -

```
- (FSItem *)createItem
{
    FSItem *item = [[FSItem alloc] init];

    if (i < [animals count])
    {
        [item setTitle: [[item animals] objectAtIndex: i]];
        [item setSound: [[item sounds] objectAtIndex: i]];
        [item setPlays: 0];
        i++;

        [allItems addObject: item];
    }

    return item;

}
```

This is still a bad way of doing what you want, as the NSArray will be initialized everytime you create an item. If the number of sounds and animals is fixed, better define them so that they just get initialized once e.g. static objects in FSItem or property on FSItemStore

Comment: To pick your brain so that i get a better understanding in addition to further clarifying, the end goal of the app is for users to be able to record and submit their own sounds.  Doesn't this mean that once i implement parse it would have to recreate the array in order to grab all the new user submitted info?

Comment: The methods animal and sounds in FSItem led me to believe that there is a fixed number of 11 animals and sounds from which the user can pick. In that case it would be better to initialize the arrays just once and use the same arrays everywhere in your code. But if the user can actually add to the number of animals and sounds then you are right, you would have to recreate the array every time a new sound was added. But the code that you have would need to be changed as it is restricted to 11 sounds.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined any properties or variables that are called animals or items. You have only defined the getter methods.

e.g.

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray *animals;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray *items;
```

Then the implementation of your getters, would return these properties.

Comment: Tried this. It got rid of the method definition error but animals is still undeclared (did you mean _animals).  also sound is now giving me "implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'SystemSoundID' (aka unsigned long') is disallowed with ARC.  not quite sure what i can do to fix that.